# Any sublime plugin to make angular view template smarter

Tags: angular, sublimetext3

Working in sublime on angular(2/4) is great until I am in the view template file. The interpolation cannot provide auto-completion for class properties backing the view, which I have seen it working by using VS Code.

Is there any plugin to make this work in sublime 3?

Comment: I followed the official guide at https://angular.io/guide/language-service . But it turnt out failed to make typescript works in ng template html file. Seeking the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

The VS Code extension that enables smart templates for Angular is [Angular Language Service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template).

A google search for 'angular language service sublime' brought up [this blog](http://brianflove.com/2017/04/11/angular-language-service/). It has a section for adding the plugin to Sublime as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typescript plugin for sublime which I use for angular 2 projects.

You can install that package by pressing "Ctrl+Shift+P" from the sublime text editor, type "Install Package" , type "Typescript", and select and install one with "IO Wrapper".

After successful installation, select typescript from right bottom dropdown in the sublime editor.

This would show color coding or syntax highlighting.